# Ruby submit_tag button not doing anything

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, submit

I want to create a `form_tag` in my `index` view to accept an `id` which gets passed to my `populateOne` method. The view has been updated properly, both the `number_field_tag` in the form and the `submit_tag` are there, but when I press the button on my server, nothing happens!

Here is my view:

```
<%= form_tag('/affinities/populateOne/:id', method: :put) %>
  <%= number_field_tag(1) %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Populate One' %><br>
```

Here are my routes: EDIT:

```
put 'affinities/populateOne/:id' => 'affinities#populateOne', :as => 'populateOne_affinity'
```

My `populateOne` method is long, so here is the relevant part:

```
def populateOne
    userA = User.find(params[:id])
    ...
end
```

What could be the problem? All help is very much appreciated! Thanks!!!

Comment: Please post your web server log that gets generated when you click the submit button. And by "nothing" do you mean that the page does not change at all? It reloads the same page?

Comment: Also post the actual HTML generated by your `submit_tag`, I think that might be part of your problem.

Comment: @Bearteach 
By "nothing", I mean that nothing loads, changes, happens, etc.

Comment: As for the server log, there is nothing recorded.

Comment: And the HTML generated? Just because the button appears on the page doesn't mean you have generated HTML that will work. Need to see the entire form.

Comment: Everything I posted for the `index` view is what I have written for the `form_tag`. I will update above with the whole view.

Comment: Is this what you mean by HTML generated?

Comment: I don't really want the view at this point. I want the ACTUAL HTML that is generated in the browser. Go to your view in the browser and view the HTML. Post it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79053/discussion-between-user107680-and-beartech).

Answer (score 1):

Your `form_tag` is posting data to the url using `put` method. And your route has `get` method. Fix it with `put`:

```
put 'affinities/populateOne/:id' => 'affinities#populateOne', :as => 'populateOne_affinity'
```

Answer (score 0):

View:
`<%= form_tag('/affinities/populateOne/:id', method: :put) %>`

Route:
`get 'affinities/populateOne/:id' => 'affinities#populateOne', :as => 'populateOne_affinity'`

Your form submit method and your route don't match. Your form is putting, and doing what you want it to, but the route is trying to get something that isn't there. Change the route's `get` to `put` and it should work as intended.

Comment: I updated the route to a `put`, good call, but the button still is not doing anything,

Comment: What is the form supposed to be doing exactly? If it's creating an object, that's one route, editing is another, and so on. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I want the user to be able to enter an `id`, submit it, and that route to a method `populateOne`.

Answer (score 0):

In my `index` view, I forgot to put `do ... end` for the `form_tag`:

```
<%= form_tag('/affinities/populateOne/:id', method: :put) do %>
  <%= number_field_tag(1) %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Populate One' %>
<% end %><br>
```